# VCS + IssueTracking + CI for free?

Tags: agile, pm-software, communication, development-process, work-environment

What is the best way to build an IT infrastructure based on a *free* / affordable *online* services (GitHub, BitBucket, etc)?

To facilitate collaborative work of a group of independent remote developers (2-5) I need

- a Version Control system to store the code
- an Issue Tracking system to manage tasks and progress and communication (preferably agile, some sort of virtual task board would be great)
- a CI server to build and deploy the solution

For the moment we don't have any of those. And we are very sensitive for price. I am considering options and I really need a piece of advice here. Any ideas? What might be a good set up?

Thanks!

Comment: As phrased, this is an architectural question, not a project management question. Since it's also a "searchy" question, it probably isn't a good candidate for migration either.

Comment: Hi @CodeGnome, there's a [discussion on this question on Meta PMSE](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/519/34). I agree w/yegor that issue tracking part is on-topic, but I'm thinking this might not be a very constructive question, especially looking at the answers, which just list products. This is pretty much a shopping question. [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). I'm closing it as not constructive. If anyone wants to make a case to reopen they can edit, vote to reopen and/or create a meta post.

Answer (score 4):

- [Github](http://github.com)

  - Git for Version Control
  - Issue tracking with milestones
- [Travis-CI](http://travis-ci.org)

  - Continuous Integration

Both of these are hosted for you.

Both of these have host-yourself options.

Answer (score 2):

The Atlassian suite may fit your needs. All of their products start at $10 and they cover the full range of tools that you've asked for.

- [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview)

  - Bug Tracker and Issue Tracker
  - With [Greenhopper](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview) plugin, adds Agile taskboard and project management tools
- [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview)

  - Source Control tool, similar to GitHub, BitBucket, etc
  - With [Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview), allows code review
- [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview)

  - Continuous Integration tool

There is a hosted version of all of the products, although I'm not sure if the cost is too great. The integration between all of Atlassian products is really slick and fairly well thought out.

Comment: Looking at $40/month on their hosted plan with these options: https://my.atlassian.com/ondemand/signup

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [Microsoft's Team Foundation Service preview](http://tfspreview.com/). It does offer the features that you're looking for. It is currently free while in preview and the [pricing](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/pricing/information/) page indicates there will be *some* level of free service available once it fully launches.

Answer (score 1):

Assembla have full set of PM&VCS tools (some plans are rather cheap), external CI tools can be  integrated with the help of Assembla's WebHooks and FTP

Answer (score 0):

I once worked in a software development house where the project management strategy goes along these lines. This might be a little expensive but some of the options are free for any developer to use.

- Tortoise SVN (Client) and Visual SVN Server (Server) for Version and Source Control.
- Hudson or Jenkins for Continuous Integration.
- Bugzilla for Issues Tracking and Management.
- Fortify 360 or Sonar for Static Source Code Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com) (I'm a co-founder). It offers SVN, Trac, and Jenkins for free in the cloud. All in one package, just as you need.